# onMessage() in GCMIntentService is not being called

Tags: android, http, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

onRegister is being called but onMessage is never called. I am getting proper responce from my php server but this methos is never called.
You can find the detail project code from here 
http://pastie.org/9168596

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chatuidemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
         android:name="com.example.chatuidemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.chatuidemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
               android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                 <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.chatuidemo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: please find the manifest here.http://pastie.org/9168666

Comment: http://pastie.org/9168666

Comment: @Eran find the manifest.

Comment: The link doesn't show the xml. Make sure that you declared the GcmBroadcastReceiver with the correct intent-filter and GcmIntentService.